# Couldn't find Workout without an ID Error With Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I have a set of nested routes that look like this:

```
  resources :workouts do
    resources :exercises do
      resources :reports, shallow: true
    end
  end
```

I tried to make them as shallow as possible, but not nesting them simply generated too many errors.

Right now they're working fine except when I try to access the `exercises#index` page for a specific workout.  I'm linking the page like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Add/Edit Exercises', workout_exercises_path(@workout, exercise), method: :index %>
```

And when I click that link I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /workouts/3/exercises
Couldn't find Workout without an ID
```

The error is called on my `exercises_controller` on the indicated line:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
      @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id]) <<<<<THIS LINE
      @exercise = Exercise.new
      @exercises = Exercise.all
  end

  def new
    @exercise = Exercise.new
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.new(exercise_params)
    exercise.user = current_user

    if exercise.save
      flash[:notice] = "Results saved successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Results failed to save."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])

    if exercise.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  private

  def exercise_params
      params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :needs_seconds, :needs_weight, :needs_reps, :workout_id)
  end

  def authorize_user
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user == current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to create or delete an exercise."
      redirect_to [exercise.workout]
    end
  end
end
```

The `friendly.find` is because I am using the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem, which generates slugs instead of ids in the url.  I use it in the same manner in other working models, so I do not believe this is causing the current problem.

Can anyone see why I'm getting this error? I have typed `@workout` into the live shell of my error and it says that `@workout` is `nil`, which means it isn't getting the value somehow.  I know this is important information, but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

- Your route was `/workouts/3/exercises`, so it format like: `/workouts/:workout_id/exercises`
- So just modify your `create` method a bit:

  ```
  def create
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.build(exercise_params)
    ...
  end
  ```

Comment: This I think got through the original error, but now it has a problem with my params:

`param is missing or the value is empty: exercise`

Comment: And will I have to modify the correlative section of my `destroy` method as well?

Comment: Add debug breakpoint inside this method `exercise_params` and see which param is missing!

Comment: I don't know how to do a debug breakpoint, but when I put @exercise into my error message's live shell it came back as `nil`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Make sure your params has this format {exercise: {name: ..., ...}} because you require `exercise`

Comment: The current params are:  `def exercise_params
      params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :needs_seconds, :needs_weight, :needs_reps, :workout_id)
  end`

Comment: Yes I see, what is the param values before running `exercise_params`, it may miss what you expected

Comment: Sorry.  How do I find that out?

Answer (score 0):

```
  def index
      @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
      @exercise = Exercise.new
      @exercises = Exercise.all
  end
```

Try this one, Hope this would help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with this change I still get `param is missing or the value is empty: exercise` called on the params of my `exercise_controller`.